# How to use ModernUI with just a Usercontrol WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, modern-ui

I wanting to you the styles from ModernUI with just a UserControl meaning i have no app.xaml file and i am unsure how to reference firstfloor.ModernUI in just to a usercontrol to inherit the styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the styles as resources in your user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Dark.xaml"/>
...
```